# Keras model ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 90

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My current model is:

```
# from tensorflow.keras.layers import InputLayer
model_training = Sequential()
# input_layer = keras.Input(shape=(300,1))
model_training.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(300,1)))
model_training.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='tanh'))
model_training.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_training.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
model_training.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_training.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='tanh'))
model_training.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_training.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
# model_training.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model_training.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='tanh'))
# model_training.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model_training.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
# model_training.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model_training.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='tanh'))
# model_training.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model_training.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
# model_training.add(Dropout(0.2))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_training.add(Flatten())
model_training.add(Dense(90))
model_training.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model_training.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model_training.summary())
```

My fit function:

```
model_training.fit(train_data, train_labels, validation_data=(test_data, test_labels), batch_size=32, epochs=15)
```

I get this error when I run this:

```
ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 90 for '{{node Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze)' with input shapes: [?,90].
```

Any idea?
my output layer has 90 as there are 90 classes in total to give a prediction on.

The train and labels are shaped as follows:

```
(7769, 300, 1)
(7769, 90, 1)
```

I can't figure out this issue. Any help is appreciated!
Partial model summary:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Squeeze your labels before training:

```py
train_labels = tf.squeeze(train_labels, axis=-1)
```

It seems like the shape of your labels is the problem. The model will output a shape of `(batch, 90)`, but you are providing `(batch, 90, 1)`. Keras is unable to squeeze dimension 1 because it has a length of 90 and not 1.

Comment: This worked. I squeezed the train_labels and test_labels and it worked. Thank you!